# `send`ing into `zip`ped generators with `yield from`

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator, yield, yield-from

I am using Python 3.6 where you can nicely `zip` individual generators of one kind to get a multidimensional generator of the same kind. Take the following example, where `get_random_sequence` is a generator that yields an infinite random number sequence to simulate one individual asset at a stock market.

```python3
import random
from typing import Iterator

def get_random_sequence(start_value: float) -> Iterator[float]:
    value = start_value
    yield value

    while True:
        r = random.uniform(-.1, .1) * value
        value = value + r
        yield value

g = get_random_sequence(1.)
a = [next(g) for _ in range(5)]
print(a)
# [1.0, 1.015821868415922, 1.051470250712725, 0.9827564500218019, 0.9001851912863]
```

This generator can be easily extended with Python's `zip` function and `yield from` to generate successive asset values at a simulated market with an arbitrary number of assets.

```python3
def get_market(no_assets: int = 10) -> Iterator[Sequence[float]]:
    rg = tuple(get_random_sequence(random.uniform(10., 60.)) for _ in range(no_assets))
    yield from zip(*rg)

gm = get_market(2)
b = [next(gm) for _ in range(5)]
print(b)
# [(55.20719435959121, 54.15552382961163), (51.64409510285255, 53.6327489348457), (50.16517363363749, 52.92881727359184), (48.8692976247231, 52.7090801870517), (52.49414777987645, 49.733746261206036)]
```

What I like about this approach is the use of `yield from` to avoid a `while True:` loop in which a tuple of *n* assets would have to be constructed explicitly.

**My question is: Is there a way to apply `yield from` in a similar manner when the `zip`ped generators receive values over `send()`?**

Consider the following generator that yields the ratio of successive values in an infinite sequence.

```python3
from typing import Optional, Generator

def ratio_generator() -> Generator[float, Optional[float], None]:
    value_last = yield
    value = yield
    while True:
        ratio = 0. if value_last == 0. else value / value_last
        value_last = value
        value = yield ratio

gr = ratio_generator()
next(gr)    # move to the first yield
g = get_random_sequence(1.)
a = []
for _v in g:
    _r = gr.send(_v)
    if _r is None:
        # two values are required for a ratio
        continue
    a.append(_r)
    if len(a) >= 5:
        break
print(a)
# [1.009041186223442, 0.9318419861800313, 1.0607677437816718, 0.9237896996817375, 0.9759635921282439]
```

The best way to "`zip`" this generator I could come up with, unfortunately, does not involve `yield from` at all... but instead the ugly `while True:` solution mentioned above.

```python3
def ratio_generator_multiple(no_values: int) -> Generator[Sequence[float], Optional[Sequence[float]], None]:
    gs = tuple(ratio_generator() for _ in range(no_values))
    for each_g in gs:
        next(each_g)

    values = yield
    ratios = tuple(g.send(v) for g, v in zip(gs, values))

    while True: # :(
        values = yield None if None in ratios else ratios
        ratios = tuple(g.send(v) for g, v in zip(gs, values))

rgm = ratio_generator_multiple(2)
next(rgm)    # move to the first yield
gm = get_market(2)
b = []
for _v in gm:
    _r = rgm.send(_v)
    if _r is None:
        # two values are required for a ratio
        continue
    b.append(_r)
    if len(b) >= 5:
        break
print(b)
# [(1.0684036496767984, 1.0531433541856687), (1.0279604693226763, 1.0649271401851732), (1.0469406709985847, 0.9350856571355237), (0.9818403001921499, 1.0344633443394962), (1.0380945284830183, 0.9081599684720663)]
```

Is there a way to do something like `values = yield from zip(*(g.send(v) for g, v in zip(generators, values)))` so I can still use `yield from` on the `zip`ped generators without a `while True:`?
(The given example doesn't work, because it doesn't refresh the `values` on the right-hand side with the `values` on the left-hand side.)

I realize that this is more of an aesthetic problem. It would still be nice to know though...

Comment: @C.Nivs: It's syntactically valid. It might not mean what the questioner wants it to mean, though.

Comment: @C.Nivs thanks for your comment! i just wanted to give an example of what I want to achieve. but that boils the problem down to the fact that it seems like you cannot use `yield from` together with `send`, independent from whether generators are `zip`ped or not... would you agree?

Comment: You can use `yield from` with `send` - in fact, one of the reasons for introducing `yield from` was `send` support. However, you can only do this if you're `yield from`-ing over a generator, not just any iterator. `zip` isn't a generator.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks! but doesn't `yield from` redirect control flow to the generator it... well... yields from? where would I `send` sth. to this generator with each iteration? could you maybe give me an example?

Comment: https://ideone.com/3z9QHM

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica nice! thanks a lot! i support monica as well! if you give your comment as an answer I'll accept it when after a few days nothing else comes up.

Comment: I don't consider it an answer, since it doesn't really address the whole zip issue - it's just a demonstration of how `send` and `yield from` interact.

Comment: Writing a `zip` compatible with `send` will probably involve reimplementing `yield from` manually, including the tricky parts of `send`/`throw`/`close` forwarding and exception handling.